# Array length is showing incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm confused about why this is not working: when I print the array lengths for two exact arrays, holding graphics objects, they are different. I'm using Javascript. Can someone pls help? Thanks.

Here's the code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        var tile = new Circle(30);
        tile.setPosition(i * 3 * tile.getRadius() + tile.getRadius() * 2, j * 3 * tile.getRadius() + tile.getRadius() * 2);
        tile.setColor(colors[Randomizer.nextInt(0, colors.length - 1)]);
        add(tile);
    }   tiles.push(tile);
}    
println(tiles.length);


for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
        var black = new Circle(30);
        black.setPosition(r * 3 * black.getRadius() + black.getRadius() * 2, c * 3 * black.getRadius() + black.getRadius() * 2);
        black.setColor(Color.black);
        black.isFilled = false;
        after.push(black);
    }
}
println(after.length);
```

Comment: How can we know if they are the same? In the first one you hardcoded `4x4` and in the other you have `cols x rows`.

Comment: by the way ... `}   tiles.push(tile);` you're pushing tile in the outer loop in the first case

Comment: @JaromandaX they seem to be using some javascript library, with `println()` and `add()`

Comment: @AdiBak can you tell us what the expected outputs are and what the actual outputs are? because the code you gave us is not runable with what you've provided

Comment: @JaromandaX I was agreeing with you

Comment: @Samathingamajig - oh, sorry

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your help. Actually Jaromanda was right that I pushed the tile into the array outside the loop. I placed it inside, and it worked then.